# Tensorflow code not producing an event file

Tags: python, tensorflow

Would anybody know why this code does not produce an event file in the current directory?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
print(sys.version)

a = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly
total = a + b
print(a)
print(b)
print(total)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.')
writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
```

Comment: This snipped actually worked for me. Do you have write permissions to the directory? Which tensorflow version are you using.

Comment: @Vlad-HC Hi yes I do have permissions. I'm using v 1.8. When I create a session then it creates a file? Is this line necessary `sess = tf.Session()`?